# Two definitions of Scheme theoretic image

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose $f：X \to Y $ is a morphism. 
I saw two definitions of scheme theoretic image.

The first one requires $f$ to be quasi-compact and quasi-separated, or quasi-compact, which ensures the kernel $J=O_Y\to f_*(O_X)$ be quasi-coherent. Thus $J$ defines a closed subscheme of Y.

The second one requires nothing, it define one by the quasi-coherent sheaf $\sum J_W$ where $J$ is the defining ideal of $W$, and $W$ runs through all the the closed subschemes $W$ which $f$ factors through.

What is there difference?

Comment: There is no difference if $f$ is qc qs, since obviously $\sum J_W = \ker(f^\#)$ then.

Comment: You can find details in the stacks project (search for scheme theoretic image).

Comment: I think Hartshorne also has a universal property definition. I don't know enough scheme theory to know which of your definitions it's equivalent to, though.

Comment: I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Martin noted, any definition of scheme-theoretic image will be compatible with the second definition you give.

---

The point is that in the absence of some (mild!) assumption on $f$, it is impossible to prove anything about scheme-theoretic image; in paticular, it is impossible to prove (since it won't be true in general) that it is local on the base (i.e.\ that for an open subset $U$ of $Y$, the sch.th.im. intersected with $U$ coincides with the sch.th.im. of $f_{|f^{-1}(U)} : f^{-1}(U) \to U$.

So people normally only speak of sch.th.im. when $f$ satisfies a hypothesis (such as quasi-compactness) which allows this property to be verified.